# flutter gives me an socket exception os error connection timed out erno=110

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core

my Flutter app on my physical device can't reach my asp.net core api it just gives me an erno:110 connection timed out
despite of my api is working fine on postman.

i also tried to replace the localhost with the ipv4 address in the http.get() url in my flutter app and connected my phone and my computer to the same network and it gives me the same error

here is how iam trying to reach my API

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show Client;
import 'package:Names/Models/Names.dart';

class ApiService {
  
  final String baseUrl = "http://192.168.0.102:5000/api";
  Client client = Client();
  Future<List<Names>> getNames() async {
    final response = await client.get("$baseUrl/command");
    if (response.statusCode == 200)

    {
      
      return fromJson(response.body);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code how are you trying to access your API?

Comment: sure , i just added it. although iam pretty sure the proplem some how is in the Program.cs file in my asp.net core API project